# Whitespace on option value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a select menu thats the code:

```
<select>
   <option value='Hello World'></option>
</select>
```

In later when I try to get this options value he returns 'Hello'. not 'Hello World'
and I create options like that:

```
function getTeams(tournamentTeams){
tournamentTeams.forEach(element => {
    players += "<option value="+element[0]+">"+element[0]+"</option>";
    console.log(players + "\n")
})
return players;}
```

tournamentTeams is array :

```
 tournamentTeams = [
   ['Team A', 'player1', 'player2'],
   ['Team B', 'player1', 'player2']
  ]
```

and thats the options that getTeams() function made:

```
<option value='Team' A>Team A</option>
<option value='Team' B>Team B</option>
```

How can I fix  that?

Comment: can you post the code you use to get the option value please?

Comment: That shouldn't happen, the quotes around the value should prevent it. Please post the code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: *"when I try to get this options value"* - Where/how are you doing that?  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Show how you are getting the value.

Comment: Are you creating the option dynamically? Make sure that it includes the quotes.

Comment: Assuming that option is selected, the `value` property of the `HTMLSelectElement` will be `"Hello World"` (and that will be the `value` of the `HTMLOptionElement` in any case): https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/07rpan2f/  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: I edited it I think problem is in creating

Comment: @angrycreon: Indeed. Take a look at this line: `players += "<option value="+element[0]+">"+element[0]+"</option>";` You're not wrapping the `value` in *quotes*.  So your resulting HTML is *not* `<option value='Hello World'></option>` as you originally indicated. Instead, it would be: `<option value=Hello World></option>` Which the browser interprets as: `<option value='Hello' World></option>` Wrap the value in quotes: `players += '<option value="'+element[0]+'">'+element[0]+'</option>';`

Comment: @David move that to an answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't quote your value at `"<option value="+element[0]+">"` so it becomes `<option value=Team A>` which will will result in `<option value='Team' A>`.

To avoid such problem you should not create your HTML by concatenating strings, use the DOM API instead.

By using [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) you done need to take care about escaping and the quotes, as this is done by the DOM API for you.

```js
function addTeamsToSelect(tournamentTeams, selectElement) {
  tournamentTeams.forEach(element => {
    // create the option element
    let option = document.createElement('option')
    
    // set its value
    option.setAttribute('value', element[0])
    
    // set the text that is displayed
    option.innerText = element[0]
    
    // append the option element to the select element
    selectElement.appendChild(option)
  })
}

let tournamentTeams = [
  ['Team A', 'player1', 'player2'],
  ['Team B', 'player1', 'player2']
]

addTeamsToSelect(tournamentTeams, document.querySelector('select'))
```

```html
<select></select>
```

If you want want to stay with your approach that returns the `option` elements you can use a document fragment ([`document.createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)):

```js
function getTeams(tournamentTeams, selectElement) {
  let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()

  tournamentTeams.forEach(element => {
    // create the option element
    let option = document.createElement('option')
    
    // set its value
    option.setAttribute('value', element[0])
    
    // set the text that is displayed
    option.innerText = element[0]
    
    // append the option element to the document fragment
    fragment.appendChild(option)
  })
  
  return fragment
}

let  tournamentTeams = [
  ['Team A', 'player1', 'player2'],
  ['Team B', 'player1', 'player2']
]

document.querySelector('select').appendChild(getTeams(tournamentTeams))
```

```html
<select></select>
```